# How to find if part of string appears more than one time SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, string-comparison

I have a task to do in SQL Server. I have a table containing 2 columns (ID, Sortkey) that looks like this.

```
ID        Sortkey
1         00
2         01
3         0101
4         0102
5         02
6         03
7         0301
8         030101
9         04
10        0401
```

I have a task to write '+' in front of string, if similar string start appears in a table, and '-' if it doesn't.

The output should look like this:

```
ID         Sortkey
1          -00
2          +01
3          -0101
4          -0102
5          -02
6          +03
7          +0301
8          -030101
9          +04
10         -0401
```

I've tried with count(*) but don't know how to count if there is a record with similar part of string. I imagined the solution with 2 possibilities, one would search if there is any string that contains the same part as whole string I'm looking at and return **+** in front of string, and **else** would return **-**.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `OUTER APPLY` to count similar rows, then when the count is greater than 0 use `+`, otherwise use `-`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, SortKey VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @T (ID, SortKey)
VALUES
    (1, '00'), (2, '01'), (3, '0101'), (4, '0102'), (5, '02'),
    (6, '03'), (7, '0301'), (8, '030101'), (9, '04'), (10, '0401');

SELECT  T1.ID, SortKey = CASE WHEN d.SimilarKeys > 0 THEN '+' ELSE '-' END + T1.SortKey
FROM    @T AS T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    @T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.SortKey LIKE T1.SortKey + '%'
            AND     T2.ID != T1.ID
        ) AS d (SimilarKeys);
```

**PERFORMANCE TEST**

I have commented about performance on another answer, so thought it best to at least include how I tested it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.T;
CREATE TABLE dbo.T(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SortKey VARCHAR(10));
INSERT dbo.T (ID, SortKey)
SELECT  TOP 100000
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 
        RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10000)), 
                CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 8))
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

And the queries I used for testing were:

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN d.SimilarKeys > 0 THEN '+' ELSE '-' END + T1.SortKey)
FROM    dbo.T AS T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    dbo.T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.SortKey LIKE T1.SortKey + '%'
            AND     T2.ID != T1.ID
        ) AS d (SimilarKeys);
```

**QUERY 2**

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  t1.ID, t1.Sortkey, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN  t2.sortkey like t1.sortkey + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID) AS ContainsCount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.id) AS rnr
    FROM    dbo.T AS t1
            LEFT JOIN dbo.T AS t2 
                ON t1.ID <> t2.ID
)
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN ContainsCount > 0 THEN '+' ELSE '-' END + Sortkey) AS Sortkey 
FROM    cte 
WHERE   rnr  = 1;
```

I gave up running both queries after 3 minutes, neither query performs well, This did not surprise me that much, since it requires 100,000 nested loops each one searching 100,000 rows with no index. So I added an index to the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__SortKey ON dbo.T (SortKey);
```

In this case query 1 ran in about 14 seconds each time I ran it, I gave up running query 2 after 10 minutes this time. I reduced the number of rows in the table down to 1,000 and Query 2 finally ran to completion (8 seconds), and it became apparent why it performed so badly when looking at the IO:

**Query 1**

> Table 'T'. Scan count 1001, logical reads 2031

**Query 2**

> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 15, logical reads 2061426
>   Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
>   Table 'T'. Scan count 8, logical reads 25

So query 2 required 2 million reads on only 1,000 records, which explains the slow performance.

Answer (score 1):

This Sql might not be the most efficent on big tables, but it produces the desired result.

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T2 WHERE T2.SortKey LIKE T1.SortKey + '%') > 1 THEN '-' ELSE '+' END + T1.SortKey AS SortKey
  FROM Table1 T1
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using a subselect

```
Update t1
set sortkey = CONCAT(
  (CASE WHEN (
               SELECT count(*) 
               from @table t2 
               where t2.SortKey like Concat(t1.SortKey, '%')
             ) > 1 
  THEN '+'
  ELSE '-'
  END)
  , sortKey) 
from @table t1
```

Basic idea is that you are counting all of the records that you are counting all of the rows where the SortKey is like SortKey%

this means if you have two rows with the same sort key then they both will get the +

if you want to avoid that you can and

```
and t2.sortkey <> t1.sortkey
```

to the end of the where in the select statment